# Not able to buffer special characters

Tags: java, android

```
  while (!bStop) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    inputStream.read(buffer);
                    int i = 0;

                    for (i = 0; i < buffer.length && buffer[i] != 0; i++) {
                    }
                    final String strInput = new String(buffer, 0, i);

                    System.out.println(strInput);`
}
```

The inputstream data is coming in encrypted form in bytes. When i print the data i get funny characters. How can i directly convert the inputstream to **hexadecimal** in a form of ->  01 2A 03 AA.

Please Help.

Comment: You can't pretend that binary is plain text without getting "funny" characters.  If you want to print all the bytes as hexidecimal, you can use `Integer.toHexDecimal(buffer[i]);`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hi, what library function is Integer.toHexDecimal??

Comment: sorry, it is `Integer.toHexString()` Integer is a standard class, you don't even have to import it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
byte[] array = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
```